# Tagsinput bootstrap não funciona

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, input

Estou usando o [bootstrap tags input](http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/bootstrap3/) em conjunto com [Bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/) e não estou conseguindo fazer funcionar o [typehead](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/) 
Código:

```
$('#tags').tagsinput();
   $('#tags').tagsinput({
       typeahead: {
       source: $.get('tags.php')
    }
});
```

o retorno de tags.php é

```
["Uruguaiana","Porto Alegre","Sao Paulo","Rio de Janeiro","Salvador"]
```

Alguém sabe me dizer qual é o problema?

Comment: Consegui fazer funcionar incluindo o bootstrap-tagsinput.min.js.map no diretório, porém o css ficou estranho

Comment: Achou alguma solução? Poste como resposta para ajudar outras pessoas.

Comment: Na verdade acho até que achei, vou procurar aqui, mas deixei de usar

Comment: Então poste a solução para ajudar outros usuários :D